someone much too enthusiastic about something that doesn't concern them
A group of people is too interested, enthusiastic, and excited about a basketball tournament taking place in Armenia when they live in the farthest country from Armenia in the world—New Zealand. They don't play basketball, they have never visited Armenia and never will, and they have no acquaintance with Armenia, etc.
So, someone is mocking them, saying, "You people are so enthusiastic about an Armenian basketball tournament in which even native Armenians are not interested! It reminds me of an idiom/phrase/proverb ...!"
What idiom/phrase/proverb can represent this situation?

This doesn't sound like a common event that there's a phrase for.

These days it's common (for instance) for people in the UK to be obsessive over South Korean pop music, and Thai teenagers to obsess over English football, so I agree there's unlikely to be a phrase in this globalized world. And it's a bit weird to be making judgments over what people should be interested in. But if necessary you could make something up based on what you personally consider atypical.


Someone who is much too enthusiastic about something that doesn't
concern them can be called a buttinsky.

buttinsky (n.)

Variants or less commonly buttinski
A person given to butting in : a troublesome meddler
M-W


Colloquial (originally U.S.).
A person who butts in, interrupts, or interferes; a busybody, a
meddler.
Originally and frequently as a humorous surname.
1901 I observe that you are a member of the Buttinski Family.
Chicago Sunday Tribune 17 November 60
[OED online]



Buttinsky is a mock surname formed by attaching the Slavic ending -sky to butt in, 'intrude,' and was in use by 1902. Classically, a Buttinsky was a busybody who walked the streets of the Lower East Side asking "How's business?"
Irving Allen; The City in Slang
(1995)


"I don't want to eat. I want to know if I am playing with Carl next
time or am I being replaced by this—this ..." Becky looked around
wildly as if she expected on of the others to supply the name she was
searching for to call Ruth. When no one came to her assistance, she
blurted out, "Buttinsky!"
Rita Silver; Second Chances (2015)


A more general expression, but with an apt locative allusion, is


That's not just left field, it's a whole different stadium.


[Ms Cardeno; Reddit]

left field
[1] [singular noun]
If you say that someone or something has come out of left field or is
out in left field, you mean that they are [or it is] untypical, unusual, or
strange in some way.
[2] [adjective] ... [mainly British, informal]
Left-field means slightly odd or unusual.

...a left-field cabaret act
Her parents were creative and left-field and wanted Polly to become a singer or a truck driver.


[Collins]
